# How to get your public ip address using Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a gui for an net address etc. calculator. All the coding is done but now i want to have a button that will get your computer's ip address. I was looking for a solution and saw various posts on stackoverflow but none of them work for me...

*Edit: this piece of code worked for me*

````
QTcpSocket socket;
    socket.connectToHost("8.8.8.8", 53);
    if (socket.waitForConnected()) {
        QString text = socket.localAddress().toString();
        ui->ipAddress->setText(text);

    } else {
        QMessageBox msg;
        msg.setText("Couldn't connect to the DNS server! No internet connection...");
        msg.setWindowTitle("No internet connection");
        msg.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
        msg.exec();
    }```
````

Comment: Net address calculator... pardon, what? Host's IP address is a parameter of network interface configuration for which you clearly got API to work with, anything external may be reached only by external means ( and hardware)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the class you are looking for is the [QNetworkInterface](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html) class.

From the man page:

> The QNetworkInterface class provides a listing of the host's IP
> addresses and network interfaces.

For example, calling [QNetworkInterface::allAddresses()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html#allAddresses) is a quick way to get a list of all the IP addresses on your machine.  As for which one is the "public IP address", that's not a well-defined concept.  On most modern consumer setups, it's arguable that there is no public IP address, as consumer PCs are typically hidden behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) layer, and as such the only public IP address is on the network router, not on the user's computer itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use QHostInfo for this purpose. Ex;
auto list = QHostInfo::fromName(QHostInfo::localHostName()).addresses();

Answer (score 0):

I am using following code snippet in my current project to get ip address. And it is working fine both on Desktop Linux and Embedded Linux. `device` is network interface name like "wlan0", "eth0" etc. It returns [QNetworkAddressEntry](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaddressentry.html) which contains both ip and netmask. Use [ip()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaddressentry.html#ip) function get ip address. Usually the first address entry is non-virtual one, so that's why am getting the first one.

```
const QNetworkInterface& networkInterface = QNetworkInterface::interfaceFromName(device);

if (networkInterface.isValid())
{
    const QList<QNetworkAddressEntry>& addressEntries = networkInterface.addressEntries();

    if (!addressEntries.isEmpty())
        return addressEntries.front();
}

return QNetworkAddressEntry(); // could not found, invalid adress entry
```

Don't forget to add `QT += network` to your pro file.

Answer (score 0):

Using QNetworkAccessManager, you can tap this free REST api: https://www.ipify.org/

That supports various options, such as returning the results in json.  If you simply **get** that url, it will respond with the ip address you are most likely hoping to get back, in a raw format (i.e. a naked string).